# Should the submit buttons stay in the fixed area?

Tags: website-design

[image]

It seems nice in the long forms, but rather weird in the short ones.

1. There are much more long forms than short ones in our website, so is it reasonable to put the submit buttons in the fixed area?
2. How about making it adaptive? Is it difficult for the front-end engineer?

Comment: you could also have it in a way that it'll be just below the form in shorter forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Does it make sense for the user to submit without filling out the entire form?**

**If the user has to go through the entire form anyway, there is little point in having a submit button that is always visible**; you might as well put it at the bottom.  In fact, in this scenario having it always visible could be a negative, since it might lead to the user not seeing the whole form or trying to submit prematurely.

One might argue that the "cancel" function is always useful, but since it is a website, the user can easily press "back" anyway.  There is some question of whether a web form even needs a cancel, as [discussed here recently](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/85435/do-you-need-an-exit-or-cancel-button-for-a-multi-step-web-based-form).

On the other hand, **if submitting the form without seeing all of it is a common workflow, the always-visible submit button makes sense.**  But what about those short forms?

You could come up with a design that handles both optimally.  For example, you could have the submit button at the end of the form when that is visible on screen but persist at the bottom of the screen whenever the end of the form is not visible.

I don't see the "far away" submit button as such a huge problem, though, if shorter forms are the exception rather than the rule.  It is up to you whether you think this is worth extra development effort to address.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the common workflow, it did help! And the extended reading about 'cancel' is nice, thanks so much~ btw, 'cancel' is rather important since it serves as a 'survival capsule'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Sticky footer submit button. By doing this  the submit button is always visible and can easily be accessed regardless of one's position on the form.This can be done with the CSS position:fixed attribute.

Comment: Seems like the OP is already using a sticky footer and now needs some advice on how to handle the whitespace on short forms.